# ngx-pagination and total visible page numbers at a time

Tags: html, angular, pagination

I am using ngx pagination in my angular 6 application, all was well until it comes to total page numbers visible at a time, I have set my HTML template code as below, but as per attached image, it shows 1 .. 10. I don't want such kind of display, I want 1,2,3 at a time and when I click on next, pager display should be 2,3,4 and so on. 
[image: current pagination]

```
<pagination-controls  (pageChange)= "ChanggPage($event)" maxSize="3" >
</pagination-controls>
```

Comment: this example shows numbers as you expect https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1f9hq?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts. Please compare it with your code or share a repro in stackblitz

Comment: Please see output, it is same as I have described in my problem

Comment: Yes, please compare the code in my example with your code. Or please share your full code in stackblitz